# Type 'QuerySnapshot?' has no member 'documents'

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to get data back from the Firebase Firestore but have come in to one or maybe more problems

Here is my code

I a trying to get a specific document with the id of the current user id

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift


class UsersModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var userData = [UserData]()
    
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
            
            db.collection("users").document(userID).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let document = QuerySnapshot?.documents() else {
                    print("No documents")
                    return
                }
                
                self.userData = document.compactMap{(QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> UserData? in
                    return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserData.self)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but on this line `guard let document = QuerySnapshot?.documents() else {` I get this error `Type 'QuerySnapshot?' has no member 'documents'`

I am using the Coddle protocol

Here is my UserData

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct UserData: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username: String
    var ImageURl: URL
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this please

Many Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `QuerySnapshot?.documents` instead of `QuerySnapshot?.documents()`, without `()`

Comment: I now get this error on the same line 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894582/type-of-expression-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-swift) might be useful for the another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your snapshot is already a document so you can't query for 'documents' because it's not a collection

All you need to do is get your query snapshot from the listener closure, [querySnapshot] and get it's data like so:

```
func fetchData() {    
    db.collection("users").document(userID).addSnapshotListener { (documentSnapshot, error) in
        guard let document = documentSnapshot?.data() else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.userData = document.compactMap{(QueryDocumentSnapshot) -> UserData? in
            return try? QueryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UserData.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: on the return try? line I get this error `Value of tuple type 'Dictionary<String, Any>.Element' (aka '(key: String, value: Any)') has no member 'data'`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to read in a single user's data, which would be a single document. No reason to addSnapshotListener unless you want to be notified of changes.

Also, there's no reason to `.compactMap` because the users data can be directly read from the document.

There are many options for reading a single document and mapping it to an object; here's two:

Here's a simplifed object

```
struct UserData: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username: String
    var ImageUrl: String
}
```

Option 1 to read the user using `getDocument { (document, error)` and then casting the document to a User object after being read

```
func readUser() {
    let userID = "uid_0"
    let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(userID)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let doc = document {
            let user = try! doc.data(as: UserData.self)
            print(user.username, user.ImageUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

and then the second, super simple (and way cooler) option to map the users data to the user object when it's read in

```
func readUser2() {
    let userID = "uid_0"
    let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(userID)

    docRef.getDocument(as: UserData.self, completion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            print(user.username, user.ImageUrl)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
}
```